# Can We Build a Compilation of Common Small Talk Questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm looking to compile as big as list as possible of common small talk questions / answers that might be asked when conversing with a native German speaking individual.  German will be my 4th language behind English, French and Spanish.  I'm a native English speaker and I mostly learned French and Spanish from living in those countries.

To begin my German voyage, since I don't have those advantages, my plan is to build my conversation up to the level of being able to have a solid, "small talk" conversation with a stranger.  This is an attempt to replicate how I learned French and Spanish, just by speaking to people at gatherings, parties, etc.  I notice that you are asked and answering almost always the same types of questions.  If you're willing to help then, think of a small talk type question one might ask, translate it to German, and then the appropriate response, along with any nuances or alternative ways of saying it that might be interesting to know.

I hope this is a suitable question for this site and I very much appreciate anyone who decides to participate.  I think it would be interesting if there was one place where there was a huge collection of these kinds of questions and answers.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think Germans really do small talk. If you ask "Wie geht's Dir?" be prepared for an elaborated statement. In my experience, Germans rather cut straight to the point.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but I guess what I mean by "small talk" is imagine you are in Germany and you meet a new person or group of people and you strike up a conversation with them.  What kind of questions do you think you would get? Like what's your name, where are you from, where did you go to school, how did you learn german, what do you do for a living, etc etc.  I guess this isn't strictly limited to German but basically the the same for all languages and people - I just though it would be cool to compile a list like this in German.

Comment: I kind of think this is too broad. Especially all the follow-up questions.